# npx webpack command cannot find module webpack.config.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm following the official Webpack getting started guide and I get an error on the **Using a Configuration** section. It says to create a webpack.config.js file with:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

I then run the following command:
`npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`

The error I get is:

`Cannot find module '/Users/Documents/Web_Development/tone/webpack.config.js'`

The guide does not seem to give any ideas of what could be wrong here. Also my code editor is telling me there is an error with `const path = require('path');` saying "Expected a JSON Object, array or literal;

My Directory structure:

```
webpack.config.json 
package.json.lock
package.json
node_modules/
dist/
   index.html
   main.js
src/
   index.js
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "tone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: Cannot find errors are usually because of accessing wrong directory.

Comment: can you give your directory structure of your project?

Comment: @NathanWright I added my directory structure above.

Comment: can you try running webpack --config webpack.config.js instead? Also, what's the contents of your package.json?

Comment: I tried the command you suggested and this is what I got back: `webpack: command not found`. I've added my package.json above.

Comment: in your `Directory structure` you put `webpack.config.json` instead of `webpack.config.js` is it a mistake or...

Comment: yes, I had it as a json file. making the config a js file was the fix. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change the `webpack.config.json` file to `webpack.config.js`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the `webpack.config.js` file is in the root of your project.